# Show that $\chi(\cdot)$ is a non-trivial character on $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, characters

Let $G =  \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ an odd prime.

If $p \nmid a$ then multiplication by $a$ on the elements of G is bijective and therfore this is an permutation on G.

Define $\chi(a)$ as the signum of this permutation.

**Show that $\chi(\cdot)$ is a non-trivial character on $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.**

---

The character-part i got. 
I struggle with the *non-trivial*.

So I need to find a permutation with signum $-1$. Thought about using that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic, so that it has an generator $w$. But why defines multiplication with $w$ a (p-1)-cycle. (then it would have signum $-1$...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just write down the cycle that $w$ forms starting from $1$: it maps $1$ to $w$, $w$ to $w^2$, $w^2$ to $w^3$, and so on.  Since no positive power of $w$ is $1$ before $w^{p-1}$, this forms a cycle of length $p-1$: $(1\ w\ w^2\ \dots\ w^{p-2})$.